# Why one string writes two char in C?

Tags: c

I'm newbie and I'm trying to figure out how C works exactly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

char introduction[4] = "I am";
char who[9] = "Stargazer";

printf("%s \n", introduction);
return 0;
}
```

but output contains both char variable. Why?

Comment: `"I am"` is 4 characters + the nul terminator. Your array is too small to hold that string. Same for the other one.

Comment: Do not use images for code. Include it online in your question. BTW, your problem is that strings must have space to hold the chars PLUS the terminating '\0'. So for "I am", you need at least 5 chars, not 4.

Comment: You can also let the compiler add the terminator: `char introduction[] = "I am";`

Comment: I'm gonna look for that nul terminator subject. Thanks. It worked when I change introduction to 5 and who to 10.

Comment: Counting the characters yourself is both unnecessary and error-prone, don't do it – no extra points for making things more complicated for yourself. Just use the empty `[]` and let the compiler count it unless you specifically need to allocate a larger array than what you are initialising with.

Comment: Letting empty pretty useful. I was counting number because I just saw that in a youtube lesson. Now I know more useful way, Thanks to @WhozCraig and you Arkku :)